# error: You must be logged in to the server - the server has asked for the client to provide credentials - "kubectl logs" command gives error

Tags: kubernetes

We had setup kubernetes 1.10.1 on CoreOS with three nodes.
Setup is successfull

```
NAME                STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
node1.example.com   Ready     master    19h       v1.10.1+coreos.0
node2.example.com   Ready     node      19h       v1.10.1+coreos.0
node3.example.com   Ready     node      19h       v1.10.1+coreos.0

NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default            pod-nginx2-689b9cdffb-qrpjn       1/1       Running   0          16h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-568dfff588-zxqjj    1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-2wwcg                           2/2       Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-78nzn                           2/2       Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-gbvkn                           2/2       Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-policy-controller-6d568cc5f7-fx6bv   1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-x66dh                        1/1       Running   4          18h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-787f887b67-q6gts    1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-dns-79ccb5d8df-b9skr                   3/3       Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-proxy-gb2wj                            1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-proxy-qtxgv                            1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-proxy-v7wnf                            1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-68d5b648c-54925              1/1       Running   0          18h
kube-system   pod-checkpointer-vpvg5                      1/1       Running   0          18h
```

But when i tries to see the logs of any pods kubectl gives the following error:

> kubectl logs -f pod-nginx2-689b9cdffb-qrpjn error: You must be logged
>   in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide
>   credentials ( pods/log pod-nginx2-689b9cdffb-qrpjn))

And also trying to get inside of the pods (using EXEC command of kubectl) gives following error:

> kubectl exec -ti pod-nginx2-689b9cdffb-qrpjn bash error: unable to
>   upgrade connection: Unauthorized

**Kubelet Service File :**

```
Description=Kubelet via Hyperkube ACI
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.env
Environment="RKT_RUN_ARGS=--uuid-file-save=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid \
  --volume=resolv,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf \
  --mount volume=resolv,target=/etc/resolv.conf \
  --volume var-lib-cni,kind=host,source=/var/lib/cni \
  --mount volume=var-lib-cni,target=/var/lib/cni \
  --volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log \
  --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log"
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/checkpoint-secrets
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/inactive-manifests
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/lib/cni
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "grep 'certificate-authority-data' /etc/kubernetes/kubeconfig | awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d > /etc/kubernetes/ca.crt"
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid
ExecStart=/usr/lib/coreos/kubelet-wrapper \
  --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubeconfig \
  --config=/etc/kubernetes/config \
  --cni-conf-dir=/etc/kubernetes/cni/net.d \
  --network-plugin=cni \
  --allow-privileged \
  --lock-file=/var/run/lock/kubelet.lock \
  --exit-on-lock-contention \
  --hostname-override=node1.example.com \
  --node-labels=node-role.kubernetes.io/master \
  --register-with-taints=node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/run/kubelet-pod.uuid
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**KubeletConfiguration File**

```
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
staticPodPath: "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
clusterDomain: "cluster.local"
clusterDNS: [ "10.3.0.10" ]
nodeStatusUpdateFrequency: "5s"
clientCAFile: "/etc/kubernetes/ca.crt"
```

We have also specified "--kubelet-client-certificate" and "--kubelet-client-key" flags into kube-apiserver.yaml files:

```
- --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/secrets/apiserver.crt
- --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/secrets/apiserver.key
```

So what we are missing here?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How have you setup your kubectl? What does yout kube config file look like? Are you using the correct client/server certificates? What does `kubectl version` give you?

Answer (score 22):

In my case the problem was that somehow context was changed. Checked it by

```
kubectl config current-context
```

and then changed it back to the correct one by

```
kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

Comment: You might want to consider  `kubectl --context desired-context` instead of constantly switching your default context back and forth.

Comment: Useful suggestion @JonTroncoso

Answer (score 13):

This is a quiet common and general error which is related to authentication problems against the API Server.

I beleive many people search for this title so I'll provide a few directions with examples for different types of cases.

1 ) (*General*) 
 Common to all types of deployments - check if **credentials were expired**.

2 ) (*Pods and service accounts*) 
 The authentication is related to **one of the pods which is using a service account that has issues like invalid token**.

3 ) (*IoC or deployment tools*) 
 Running with an **IoC tool** like Terraform and **you failed to pass the certificate correctly** like in [this case](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/400#issuecomment-583561090).

4 ) (*Cloud or other Sass providers*) 
 A few cases which I encountered with AWS EKS:

4.A) **In case you're not the cluster creator - you might have no permissions to access cluster**.

When an EKS cluster is created, the user (or role) that creates the cluster is automatically granted with the `system:master` permissions in the cluster's RBAC configuration.
Other users or roles that needs the ability to interact with your cluster, need to be added explicitly - Read more in [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/#You.27re_not_the_cluster_creator).

4.B) If you're working on multiple clusters/environments/accounts via the CLI, the current profile that is used needs to be re-authenticated or that there is a **mismatch between the cluster that need to be accessed and the values of shell variables** like: `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` or `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

4.C) **New credentials** (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`) **were created and exported to the terminal which might contain old values of previous session** (`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`) and need to be replaced or unset.

---

Comment: Can you give me more info how SAML federated users can access eks clusters.I've updated the role arn in configmaps/aws-auth but still getting the error "You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)" but `aws eks get-token --cluster-name xx`  and `aws-iam-authenticator token -i cluster_name -r role-arn` is working.

Comment: Hi @user6826691, I think that this is a scope of a new question. Better to open a new thread for that.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I have noticed this issue on a running cluster which was not touched for long time - the answer is more applicable for searchers on Google as this link is at the top by error experienced in the question.

The issue was expired certificates.

You can check this on Kubernetes master server:

```
# find /etc/kubernetes/pki/ -type f -name "*.crt" -print | egrep -v 'ca.crt$' | xargs -L 1 -t  -i bash -c 'openssl x509  -noout -text -in {}|grep After'
bash -c openssl x509  -noout -text -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt|grep After
            Not After : Jan 19 14:54:15 2022 GMT
bash -c openssl x509  -noout -text -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt|grep After
            Not After : Nov 13 01:46:12 2021 GMT
bash -c openssl x509  -noout -text -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt|grep After
            Not After : Nov 13 01:46:12 2021 GMT
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you [misconfigured kublet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet-authentication-authorization/):

You missed the `--client-ca-file` flag in your **Kubelet Service File**

That’s why you can get some general information from master, but can’t get access to nodes.

This flag is responsible for certificate; without this flag, you can not get access to the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, many different .kube/config file errors will trigger this error message. In my case it was that I simply specified the wrong cluster name in my config file (and spent MANY hours trying to debug it).

When I specified the wrong cluster name, I received 2 requests for MFA token codes, followed by the `error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)` message.

Example:

```
# kubectl create -f scripts/aws-auth-cm.yaml
Assume Role MFA token code: 123456
Assume Role MFA token code: 123456
could not get token: AccessDenied: MultiFactorAuthentication failed with invalid MFA one time pass code.
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was related to mis-configuration in the ~/.kube/config file , after restoring the configurations using  kubectl config view --raw >~/.kube/config it was resolved

Comment: Please advise people to take backup first of this config file.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered that issue. After certificates renewal (kubeadm certs renew all) and control plane restart (including kubelet on all master nodes) I had to restart kubelet on all worker nodes.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I experienced multiple errors while trying to run different kubectl commands like unauthorized, server has asked client to provide credentials, etc. After spending a few hours, I deduced that the sync to my cluster on cloud somehow gets messed up. So I run the following commands to refresh the configuration and it starts to work again:

1. Unset users:

   `kubectl config unset users.<full-user-name-as-found-in: kubectl config view>`
2. Remove cluster:

   `kubectl config delete-cluster <full-cluster-name-as-found-in: kubectl config view>`
3. Remove context:

   `kubectl config delete-context <full-context-name-as-found-in: kubectl config view>`
4. Default context:

   `kubectl config use-context contexts`
5. Get fresh cluster config from cloud:

   `ibmcloud cs cluster config --cluster <cluster-name>`

Note: I am using ibmcloud for my cluster so last command could be different in your case