# Can't access API Kubernetes only on specific master

Tags: kubernetes

My configuration is 3 master nodes:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
srv-dev-k8s-master-01   Ready    control-plane,master   101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-master-02   Ready    control-plane,master   101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-master-03   Ready    control-plane,master   101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-01   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-02   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-03   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-04   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-05   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-06   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-07   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-08   Ready    <none>                 101d   v1.22.2
srv-dev-k8s-worker-09   Ready    <none>                 75d    v1.22.2
```

When I try to check the logs I get an error:

```
$ kubectl logs kube-apiserver-srv-dev-k8s-master-01
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials ( pods/log kube-apiserver-srv-dev-k8s-master-01))
```

But I can access other master nodes:

```
$ kubectl logs kube-apiserver-srv-dev-k8s-master-02
I1121 19:51:52.741596       1 server.go:553] external host was not specified, using 172.24.27.14
I1121 19:51:52.749073       1 server.go:161] Version: v1.22.2
I1121 19:51:53.179532       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 13 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,PodTolerationRestriction,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I1121 19:51:53.179548       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 12 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PodSecurity,Priority,PodTolerationRestriction,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I1121 19:51:53.180881       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for node_authorizer
I1121 19:51:53.185693       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 13 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,PodTolerationRestriction,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I1121 19:51:53.185807       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 12 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PodSecurity,Priority,PodTolerationRestriction,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.

...
```

Please tell me what could be the error and how to fix this error? Thank you.

**Additional information:**

I compared /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf configurations on all master nodes and this is what I saw:

Master1:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 
    server: https://172.24.16.6:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: system:node:srv-dev-k8s-master-01
  name: system:node:srv-dev-k8s-master-01@kubernetes
current-context: system:node:srv-dev-k8s-master-01@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: system:node:srv-dev-k8s-master-01
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
```

Master2 and Master3:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data:
    server: https://172.24.16.6:6443
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: default
    user: default-auth
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-auth
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
```

`kubectl config current-context` on Master1, Master2, Master3:

```
$ kubectl config current-context
kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
```

Based on this information, I don't understand what to do next.

Comment: Similar issue, try following the steps from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016954/error-you-must-be-logged-in-to-the-server-the-server-has-asked-for-the-client

Comment: KubePony thank for answer. I have updated the information.

Comment: Well, apparently a valid configuration is presented on our master 2 and 3. Try changing the configuration to default-cluster, default-auth and default-context, after backing up kubelet.conf. And restart the kubelet on the master node1, maybe it will help...